No .on event firing. Asp.NET Core 6, JQuery
I am building an ASP.NET Core 6, JQuery application.
I have the following JQuery on my page
@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
    <script>

        $(function () {
           $('#postcodeKnown').on('click', function () {
             alert("Changed")
           });
        });

    </script>
 }

I was wanting the on click event to fire on the following check box control -
<div class="row">
   <label class="control-label col-md-4">(02) Known</label>
   <div class="col-md-3 mb-1">
      <input id="postcodeKnown" type="checkbox" title="Please check if postcode is known." class="chkBox d-inline-flex mr-4 col-md-1" />
   </div>
</div>

The HTML rendered by the browser is -
<input id="postcodeKnown" type="checkbox" title="Please check if postcode is known." class="chkBox d-inline-flex mr-4 col-md-1">

Nothing happens when I click on the checkbox.
I have tried -
@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
    <script>

        $(function () {
            $('#<%=postcodeKnown.ClientID%>').on('click', function () {
            alert("Changed");
        });
        
    </script>
 }

Still doesn't work
I have tried it without the $(function () { around it, nothing.
At the bottom of my _layout.cshtml I have -
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
@await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

RenderPartialAsync sounds as if that process might still be ongoing, after document.ready has fired. Use event delegation.

@CBroe RenderPartialAsync is only used for the _ValidationScripts, not the HTML.  RenderPartialAsync only applies async server-side during building of the HTML, there's no ajax call - so the HTML sent to the client will be complete when the js executes.  Having said that, event delegation would rule out any order issues:  $(document).on("click", '#postcodeKnown', function() {... also check the selector (in general), eg console.log($('#postcodeKnown').length)) added just inside the doc ready callback.

Check the browser dev tools.  If there's any script errors, there will be messages in the console.  If any of the .js files can't be found, there will be errors in the network tab.  Check these first.  Next do a view-source (not inspect element) - this will provide you with the rendered HTML, which then might have something obvious (such as the input not present in the HTML!)

If the jQuery selector call matches nothing, there will be no errors reported. Delegation is the correct answer; it's almost always the correct answer.

@Pointy to play devils advocate - if the selector matches nothing, then it will also match nothing when using delegation...   delegation helps with dynamically generated HTML, which this appears not to be (given the detail in the question... so, probably is the issue!)

@fdomn-m oh certainly, yes. My point is that the habit of doing everything via delegation is a good habit to have. jQuery even "fixes" things like the "blur" event, which natively does not bubble but with jQuery it seems to.

I looked at source code, nothing out of the ordinary there.  The only errors I am getting are Migrate entirely to HTTPS to have cookies sent to same-site subresources... Todo with 3rd party cookies.  Apart from that no other errors.  The $('#postcodeKnow').length is 1.   Also tried $(document).on("click", '#postcodeKnown', function() {... to no affect.

Can you reproduce the issue here in a stack-snippet ([edit] and click [<>]) or in another isolated environment, such as jsfiddle.net?  eg A copy of your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/wa0drnvj/

"Nothing happens when I click on the checkbox.
I have tried -"  I test your code in the asp.net core mvc  project, it woks fine like: https://i.sstatic.net/mWesZ.png. You can try a new project to test.

My apologies, I looked at the source code again and the script is not there and the  await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial") is not loading.

I have solved it.  I was putting the script in the wrong place...D'oh!
I have a file CreatePatient.cshtml that was calling my patient cshtml using
@await Html.PartialAsync("_Patient", Model);

I was putting the script in my Patient cshtml instead of the CreatePatient cshtml.  Once I moved it to the CreatePatient cshtml it started to work.
Thanks for all your help.
